# Applying multiple weights

Tags: spss

I have a data set that has weighted scores based on gender and age profiles. I also have region data broken up into 7 states. I basically want to exclude one of those states and apply additional weights based on state to come up with a new "overall" score.

Manual excel calculations is only way I can think of doing this.

I need to take scores that already have a variable weight applied and add an additional weight dependent on region.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com.  Generally speaking, there are two approaches you could use:  1) a "parameter-based" weighting scheme where you calculate a weight for each variable of interest and then multiply them together (i.e. final_wt = gender_wt * age_wt * state_wt), or 2) a "cell-based" scheme where you determine a weight for each combination of gender, age, and state.  A parameter-based approach is often "good enough" for most purposes, but a cell-based scheme is more rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

SPSS Statistics only allows a single weight variable to be applied at any one time, so Kevin Troy's comments are correct: you'll have to combine things into a single weight. If the data are properly combined into a single file you may find the Rake Weights extension that's installed with the Python Essentials useful, as you can specify multiple variables as inputs to the overall weighting scheme and have the weights calculated for you. If you're not familiar with the theory behind this, look up raking or rim weighting.